# Questions regarding RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am exploring the world of Ruby and RVM. I am going through a lot of documentation and trying out RVM, but I am a bit confused about the entire work flow. I am writing down the workflow as I understand it. Can someone please take a look and see if this understanding is correct?

I am using a Mac.

- RVM is essentially a script that allows us to manage Ruby environments for development purposes.
- RVM allows switching between different versions of Ruby with `rvm use 1.9.2`.
- To use a particular gemset with the current Ruby version, we need to create a gemset using
  `rvm --create gemset rails235`
- Install the gem using `gem install rails -v=2.3.5`

> Q: What happens if I did `gem install rails -v=2.3.5` prior to creating a gemset? Will there be two copies of the same Rails installed under RVM's Ruby 1.9.2?
>
> Q: What happens if I install 2.3.5 and 3.1.0 prior to creating gemsets and then create a gemset for each version?
>
> Q: where does `rvmrc` come into picture in the whole story?

Any other information that helps me get this straight is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kiran, this is in reference to your comment above.  When you install a different version of ruby with rvm, it'll add to this list:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]
```

On my system, I've only got one version running (for now).  This helps too

```
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p290 (found in /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290)
   global
=> mg_diaspora
   rails3
   railscasts
   ruby
   sorcery
```

The practice is to install common gems into your `global` gemset and create/use sets for everything else.  I tend to keep `pry` and others in the global gemset.  As Mike K. said, you'd never do #2; if you *did* do such a thing, I would imagine `global` having priority.

**#3 .rvmrc**

You can do things like this in the file:

```
rvm use 1.9.2@rails3 --create
```

This will ensure whenever you 'cd' into the directory, it'll switch to 1.9.2 and it's 'rails3' gemset; the following attribute ensures the gemset will be created if it doesn't already exist.

**Update**

> Ex: if I say rvm use 1.9.2@rails3 --create how does this pick the version of rails3.1.0 gem
>   Because by the time this rails3 gemset is created I already have 2 versions of rails gems?

That's easy - when you run `bundle install` it creates a `Gemfile.lock`; this essentially 'locks' the gems that your application is set to use.  You've never *require* two different versions of rails in a single `Gemfile` anyways - that's just ridiculous =)

Comment: Michael,
Thanks for the explanation. Here is what I am confused about. If I do a global gem installation for rails2.3.5 and rails3.1.0, How can I create gemsets now so that they can refer to a project specific version of rails gem? Ex: if I say `rvm use 1.9.2@rails3 --create` how does this pick the version of rails3.1.0 gem? Because by the time this rails3 gemset is created I already have 2 versions of rails gems? Thx

Comment: I tend to setup gemsets for whichever version of rails I'm working on.  So you'd want to create another gemset  `rails235` and load up all your 2.3.5 specific gems in there and keep the `rails3` gemset separate.  Another approach is to create a gemset per app you're working on.

Comment: See my updated answer above to your question as well.  Do accept my answer if it satisfies you thanks.

Comment: Michael, I thought rvm is not dependent on application? Isn't that true? From your comment `when you run bundle install it creates a Gemfile.lock; this essentially 'locks' the gems that your application is set to use.`, However, I am thinking of running rvm to create multiple gemsets irrespective of application as I change the environment to this gemset and then run `rails new myapp`. But from what I see in your answer, it seems like I need to pick a global rails version first, create a project, go inside the project and then run rvm gemset create which seems to go against the principle?

Comment: I have no idea how you took my response to mean all of that - this is such a simple topic you won't believe.  Yes, RVM is not dependent on the application.  However, you could have 200 gems in a gemset but your Rails application will only use those specified in the Gemfile (and Gemfile.lock is part of that mechanism).

Comment: `But from what I see in your answer, it seems like I need to pick a global rails version first, create a project, go inside the project and then run rvm gemset create...` Gemsets and projects are not related either.  Sure, you can define a `.rvmrc` file to load a particular gemset per app - this is what I do.  **You've over complicated this entirely.**  Consider exercising some common sense perhaps and do what's best for your workflow.  My suggestion is that you create a gemset per *version* of rails or create a gemset per application.  Whatever you do, don't pollute @global or other sets.

Comment: Got you, I should have spent more time on understanding how bundler works. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

1) Rvm automatically creates an @global gemset per interpeter so if you did what you state in the first question you'd have a 2.3.5 in the global gemset.

2) I'm not sure why you would do this.

3) rvmrc is just where you can specify environment info like bashrc, i use it to specify my default architecture for instance.  It gets read when rvm gets sourced in your profile.

Comment: For 2, this is what I did when I started exploring and hadn't discovered rvm yet. Also, once this is done, couldn't figure out a way to cleanly switch between rails versions. Right now, I deleted all my installations and starting fresh but not sure what else could go wrong with this approach!

Comment: @Kiran, each rails version will have a completely different set of gemsets =)

Answer (score 0):

Basically global is a mix-in for all other gemsets under a specific interpreter. So, if you put rake and say bundler into the global gemset, and then create and enable your own gemset under that specific ruby, it will have both the gems you install in that gemset AND global.

You will see it as a single gemset though. Also, if you attempt to delete a gem that is in global while still in, say, mygemset you will not be able to delete it. This is to protect other gemsets from having gems mixed in from global that they rely on from being removed. You would have to either explicitly change to global or execute something like

```
rvm 1.9.2-p290@global exec gem uninstall rake -v='0.9.2'
```

Also, bear in mind that there is a significant difference between 'default' and 'global'. The 'default' gemset is not really a gemset perse. This is selected when you do something like

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

Notice you did not select a gemset in the above command. This is where default lives and plays. When no gemset is selected, default becomes active and global totally disappears. To load default, you would modify $rvm_path/gemsets/default.gems as these are the list of gems to be installed into each interpreter's 'default' set. The other file there is 'global.gems'. This is used as you would surmise; to load a default set of gems whenever you install a new interpreter under RVM into the global gemset, which is shared by all other gemsets for that Ruby, but **not** for 'default'.

Please see https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/ for more information.